# Failed to build pandas in python3.6

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

We are facing the issue while installing pandas on python 3.6 in our Solaris machine.

Error as below:

```
pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpp:43897: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

Failed to build pandas

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried installing gcc prior to installing pandas?  It's a compiler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#:~:text=The%20GNU%20Compiler%20Collection%20(GCC,Linux%2C%20including%20the%20Linux%20kernel.